# Is there any free GAMESS input file maker for Mac OS?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, software

My main purpose is to simulate excited state calculations on a molecule with Time Dependent DFT.

I am looking for free software that makes input files for GAMESS. I have tried Avogadro and it works fine (in Extensions> GAMESS > Input Generator > Advanced tab) but it can not make **TD-DFT** input codes.

I also checked the recommended software by the Gordon Group ([here](http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/graphics/other.html)) and tried installing some of them but couldn't install Gabedit at all (I was unable to compile the binary, maybe because I am using Mac OS X Yosemite).  I also tried WebMO but it is available just on iTunes for iOS.

What I need is a software that makes the input code interactively to avoid possible errors.

Comment: personally, I export .xyz from Avogadro and use primitive bash script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can give me the requisite keywords for TD-DFT in GAMESS, it's not hard to add that to [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/)

I've never done TDDFT in GAMESS because I use other programs, but given a link to the docs, it's easy enough to enable more drop-down menus.

That said, you can interactively edit the text in the Avogadro input for *any* quantum program (not just GAMESS).

[image]

If you don't want to use Avogadro, the "native" program for GAMESS is [MacMolPlt](http://www.scl.ameslab.gov/MacMolPlt/) which was developed in the Gordon group itself. I haven't checked, but I'd assume it supports TDDFT options, since it enables pretty much everything else in GAMESS.

Comment: @Aug I suggest you jump on Geoff's generous offer as soon as possible.  He can fix you up with an Avagadro update that may meet what you require.

Comment: Wow! I just noticed your profile, you are developer of the Avogadro and I think I've found a gold mine! Here is what I am looking for:I want to simulate reaction of Methylene Blue in Excited state( MB+ *) with some amines.I need to set up TDDFT but it is a little confusing as TDDFT=EXCITE needs DFTTYP= functional and I think it must be in RHF/UHF.Case becomes more complicated if I want to use Transitional states or Analytic nuclear gradients available in $TDDFT.I know that I can type the input commands in Avogadro but it would be awesome if it was available as some menus ( to avoid mistakes )

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Gabedit, it's in [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Just `brew install gabedit` after you install Homebrew. I just installed it without issue on Yosemite and it was pretty fast. It seems to have a lot of options for GAMESS, but it's been a long time since I've done computational chem, so I can't tell you whether it has all the TD-DFT options. I didn't get any weird errors or anything, so it seems to run fine.

Comment: Thanks!  yes I have used Homebrew and it said installation is complete but the problem is I can not find the installed software !   It is not in Application folder and a spotlight search brings up nothing!  How do you run it?

Comment: Just type gabedit into the terminal; it doesn't make an application bundle.